# What is the command line command to limit SQL 2000 server to 640MB of RAM?

Tags: sql-server

What is the command line command to limit SQL 2000 server to 640MB of RAM?   This is MSDE2000 and so I don't have access to Enterprise Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a go at this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'max server memory (MB)', 640
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

If you have to do this via a command line tool you can put that into a .sql file (LimitMaxMem.sql) and do this:

```
osql -E -S servername -i LimitMaxMem.sql
```

BTW- Enterprise Manager should hook up with MSDE just fine.  I used to use it all the time.

Comment: thanks. that was what I was looking for and it worked. ;-)

Comment: out of curiosity, which method did you use/work for you? exec or osql?

Comment: @shufler: You're running the exact same code in either case, it's just whether or not you have a GUI interface like Query Analyzer or if you're using a command line tool like osql.  With a GUI you can just type that in and execute it.  With osql you can feed in the SQL from a file (or a command line parameter, but a file's much easier).

Comment: i just realised now that the osql command was just taking the code from the file. thanks :)